# Making a barplot from pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to make a simple bar chart:
the height being frequencies of values in a Dataframe column

I have been running into this error:
ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 1 or scalar

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
flags = [200, 201, 211, 237, 239, 250, 254, 255]
frequencies = [158,  87,   5,   4]
length = len(flags)
plt.bar(length, frequencies.values, align='center')
plt.show()
```

Comment: When you say "height being frequencies of values" I hear "histogram". If you indeed want a histogram, pandas has a method built in for creating those: `df['foo'].hist()`

Answer (score 3):

Well as far as I can see in the documentation of [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar), arguments `left` and `height` must be the same length:

```
>>> plt.bar(range(len(frequencies)), frequencies, align='center')
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, that's what i thought may have been the issues but i was not sure